# html data-* attribute has to be explicitly defined with TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im writing Textinput with React and TS.

I am **extending** my TextInput-Interface with this:

```
InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>
```

This allows me to provide all native input props without explicitly define them.

*Problem* 
i receive this TS-error when i try to provide any data-* prop 
 **Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''data-whatever'' does not exist in type 'Partial'.ts(2322)**

To fix this i had to go with this workaround:

```
type DataType = `data-${string}`

interface DataFix {
    [key: DataType]: string,
}
```

From my understanding i would NOT have to go with any workaround, as data-* is global html attribute. his nephew aria-* worked perfectly fine.

Is a TS hero around to explain this behavior?